# Garbage collector doesn't deallocate linked objects (Linked Lists memory leak)

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

During development of a project I've been working on I've been working on I've encountered a problem with garbage collector not able to de-allocate linked lists or even lists.

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, previous):
        self.previous = previous
    def __del__(self):
        self.previous = None
        self = None
import gc
gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)
l = []
prev = None
for i in range(1000000):
    b = B(prev)
    l.append(b)
    prev = b

del l[:]
gc.collect()
print gc.garbage
```

When I check the memory usage before allocation and after allocation and after deletion. Memory usage after allocation is still the same as the Memory usage after deletion. and the garbage collector doesn't complain about any memory leaks.

When I use pympler to track objects in the python environment. the objects don't exist yet there's memory allocated for them.

However, This issue only arises when instances are linked. If an instances don't have a reference to each others. Garbage collector behaves normally.

Any idea why?

Comment: In the above code, after `del l[:]` your full list is still accessible via the `b` and `prev` references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have cleared out `l`, but `b` and `prev` still reference the last `B` instance created. In turn, that instance refers to the previous instance created, etc. keeping the whole chain alive:

```
>>> class B(object):
...     def __init__(self, previous):
...         self.previous = previous
...     def __del__(self):
...         self.previous = None
...         self = None
... 
>>> l = []
>>> prev = None
>>> for i in range(1000000):
...     b = B(prev)
...     l.append(b)
...     prev = b
... 
>>> del l[:]
>>> prev
<__main__.B object at 0x11f269d50>
>>> b
<__main__.B object at 0x11f269d50>
>>> b.previous
<__main__.B object at 0x11f269d10>
>>> import gc
>>> sum(1 for ob in gc.get_objects() if isinstance(ob, B))
1000000
>>> del b, prev
>>> sum(1 for ob in gc.get_objects() if isinstance(ob, B))
0
```

The `gc.garbage` list would only ever list `B` instances if there is a **circular** reference; e.g. if the last `B` instance in the chain referenced another instance in the same chain, and not `None`.

Comment: Thank you very much, rookie mistake =/

Comment: Anything missing still? You accepted then un-accepted again.

Comment: Yea actually, I viewed the concept And it's fine and correct. However, when I tried the memory usage lowered by few megs however still having 300mgbs of memory allocated for nothing.

Comment: @SaadTalaat: I can't help with that here; your specific question *here* I can answer, but your memory leak issues *in general* I cannot fix, not with the context in this question. Note that memory allocation in a process doesn't necessarily immediately drop because the OS is reluctant to move allocations around too much (computers perform better if you don't do that too much), so the deallocation of 1 million objects doesn't necessarily immediately result in a memory footprint drop.

Comment: Well, Thank you. And I was talking about your code. not my memory leak issues. :)